# The changeability though prayer?

Tags: tefilla, commentaries

One of the questions i found really interesting was the following one: [If HaShem doesn't change, then how does prayer work](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29109/if-hashem-doesnt-change-how-does-prayer-work). Of course there are some verses within the Tenach (1 Shmuel 15:29, Malachi 3:6 etc) that seem to declare that HaShem is unchangeable, but on the other hand we find Moshe and Avraham have a conversation in which they are trying to change the outcome of certain events.

Tefillah is from the root palel and so we say that prayer is ment to change ourselfes. Then I became wondering if Tefillah does change something just like the choices we make change certain outcomes. So could it be that by changing ourselfes, we could change certain outcomes (even minor ones).

It’s not going to take one major choice. But when you put together a series of choices, they create momentum and results, that will determine the results you get.

Every time you make a choice, you’re either getting closer to your goal or further away. The immediate effect might be so tiny; you won’t notice a difference.

For example, if you have that piece of cake, it’s steering you closer to gaining weight. It’s not much, but you’ve taken a tiny step in that direction. On the other hand, if you pass on the piece of cake, you’re taking a step in the other direction.

The choice to eat cake won’t have a big immediate impact in the short run, but now multiply each choice by 365 days and after a year you will have gained weight or lost weight.

If we change ourselfes and become more connected to HaShem with Tefillah, could it be that because we're changed, our view, deeds, emotions etc change, by that the outcome of certain things could change?

Comment: Why does answering a prayer have to mean God changed any more than any other decision? When I give in to a request it is not because I changed, but rather because I see fit to grant the request.

Comment: It seems to be very deep. Can you explain in what the fact that we change ourselves bypass the question you cited above.

Comment: @HaLeiVi The difficulty with that is that when your request isn't accepted, what would that mean then? Did HaShem didn't see it fit to grant?, did HaShem just didn't had the time because millions of people request something of Him. I get the point that He isn't changed when He does give in to a request, but there is a counterpart to what you're saying that doesn't seem quite right. But maybe you could help me with that.

Comment: @HaLeiVi: For a example: I knew a lot of good people, some prayed and got better, some died, in those last cases I heard some people say that prayer doesn't do anything. While I belief that even in those cases the people that died could have changed (even the slightest bit) by which they got the strength, or rest, or peace, or love, or etc.. that easened their going by, or that made it more bareable while it lasted. I try to see how prayer could effect a certain different outcome (as oposed to the situation and the most possible outcome that could come out of it)..

Comment: ... while doing no harm to HaShem, in those  cases prayer doesn't seem to have done or changed anything.

Comment: Think I found something I was looking for: http://www.chiefrabbi.co.za/?p=4691&upm_export=pdf