# Why does God modify commandments upon request?

Tags: mitzvah

I can find two instances of this in Tanach:

1) when G appoints Moshe to speak before Israel, he says he is "heavy of tongue" and G lets him use Aaron as a spokesman.

2) G commands Ezekiel (4:9) to make and eat bread baked with poop. Ezekiel politely protests and G lets him substitute cow dung.

Why does G commands one thing but allows that command to be petitioned?

Comment: מדת הדין  vs. מדת הרחמים (transitioned by prayer)

Comment: Related (general question about purpose of prayer and how it can 'change' God's mind)? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29109/if-hashem-doesnt-change-how-does-prayer-work

Comment: Are you asking about מצווה לשעה or מצווה לדורות, because you only bring two examples of מצוה לשעה - "one-time" commandments?

Comment: Even if about "one-time" commandments, do you imply that G-d is always open for petitions or only sometimes, because the Q is phrased as if G-d always modifies His commandments?

Comment: I always wondered about 2) - He gets the recipe in 4:9 and then in 4:12 it says (Chabad translation)"they shall bake it with poop before their eyes". Does this mean as part of the bread recipe, as a side dish, or as the fuel for the cooking fire?  None of the three are pleasant, but I always wondered which way was meant.  Certain cultures used(maybe still do, especially in India?) cow dung as fire fuel. Yum!

Comment: @Gary - Rashi and Metzudos clearly state that we're referring to the fuel.

Comment: You know how charcoal or wood chips alters the flavor of BBQ? Same with excrement.