# What constitutes an "Enemy of God"?

Tags: shabbat, parshanut-torah-comment, sin, vaeschanan

(I'm not referring here to Tenokim Shenishbu.)

Devarim 7: "And he repays his enemies in his lifetime to make him perish, he shall noy delay for **his enemy**, in his lifetime shall he pay him".

Who are these enemies? Is one who doesn't keep Shabbat an enemy of God as it is such a terrible sin?

Comment: It is like an Oved Avoda zara,just about right

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10207/1857